# How can I implement security in web service?

Tags: web-services, authentication

I have a REST service that is called by a mobile app; I need the user to login, then the service generates a unique token associated to user id and this pair of userId/token is passed to every subsequent call to the WS.

I don't like too much this solution because, even if very difficult, if I change the uid and get the right token I can "login" as another user, so I'm trying to understand which is the best practice to handle web service authentication for a mobile (and non) application.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not with the methodology, but the fact your service is not checking the combination of UID and token, but rather the token. That is a programming issue, not a methodology issue.

How secure do you need the service to be? Are you talking top secret level of security? Banking? My soccer club site? For high levels of security, you can use digital certificates, but it makes for a much more complex provisioning methodology. But ... Even if you are going to change from UID/Token (or AppId, User, etc), you still need to fix the fact that correct token + wrong UID works. That is a mistake if two-form authentication is a must. Changing methods will solve nothing if you don't have the proper programming on the server side to avoid circumventing the system.

You may also want to look at how you provision the Token. Should this be offline, or is one REST sign up method acceptable. This leads back to the level of security your require.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; i don't need super-high security, but i need that a user does not see other user's data.

Comment: From your post, it sounds like the UID/Token authentication needs to be fixed in the service to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to forget the token/id solution and consider going the SSL/basic authentication route.  SSL will provide the encryption and secure communication, but will not secure the access to your specific web-services on the server side.
For that you can try standard basic http user/password authentication on *every* call.  This way you do not need to worry maintaining state through each REST call. Each call will have an explicit reference to the user.  Yes, you will need to re-authenticate the user with each call which is a bit of a pain, but you can cache your results.
However, I am far from an expert on the subject.